# How do I send money to other companies?

Tags: openttd

There is an Advanced Setting: 'Allow sending money to other companies.' I have it ON. How do I actually send money?

Comment: Why would like to give money to your competitor ? The goal is to bring them to bankruptcy isn't ?

Comment: I'm currently playing a game with seven random AIs. Some are more vicious than others; the less aggressive are less successful. When an AI goes out of business the slot is immediately refilled by... another AI, not necessarily the same type (NewGRF). I'd rather subsidize stalled competition for a few thousand a year than see a new random competitor come in with a fresh few hundred grand of borrowed cash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is only possible in multiplayer.

To transfer money to other companies, you need to pen the company list  menu and click "Client list" to see which clients are connected and what company they are playing for.

If you click on a particular client, you have will have a list of various options. There is one that says "Give money" - click on that, and then you are able to give up to £20,000,000 to the selected client.